# get value of text between br using jquery text()

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's hard to work on terrible markup, it just not don't have class it look something like this:

```
<p>p</p>
<br>br1
<br>br2
<br>br3
```

to get the p is easy

```
console.log($('p').text());
```

but how to get the br1, br2 that located between `br` tag? if possible I want to check after br is there any value equal to br1, if yes then remove that line. Thought of use attr() still don't have idea how to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to use [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nextSibling) DOM property:

```
$( 'br' ).each( function() {
    console.log( $( this ).get( 0 ).nextSibling.nodeValue );
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p0rcv62u/)

Comment: you can just do `this.nextSibling` instead of `$( this ).get( 0 ).nextSibling`

Comment: if I have thousand of br, will each() caused an issue?

Comment: @user3836151 it gets node by index, you can skip it and floow other option provided in comments to this answer

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ like this console.log( $( this) .nextSibling() ); ? error.

Comment: @user3836151 like this `console.log(this.nextSibling.nodeValue );`

Comment: why I got three time alert in this case? http://jsfiddle.net/p0rcv62u/1/ I want to remove <br>br1 if br1 found.

Comment: @user3836151 because of typo. You used `=` instead of `==` na dalso note that this also adds `\n` to end of string as it in HTML layout. http://jsfiddle.net/p0rcv62u/2/