# loop through nextSibling node value confusion in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

html

```
<p>p</p>
<br>br1
<br>br2
<br>br3
```

I got 3 times alert instead of 1, why? since

```
$( function() {
    console.log($('p').text());
    $( 'br' ).each( function() {
        if(this.nextSibling.nodeValue = 'br1'){
            alert('found');
        }
    });
});
```

what I want to do is delete that line if nodevalue found, like delete `<br>br1` if br1 can be found.

Comment: I have already answered in this question to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25289309/get-value-of-text-between-br-using-jquery-text/25289403#comment39412271_25289403 . This happens beacuse HTML layout have new line after text node br1 so you need to compare by `br1\n` http://jsfiddle.net/p0rcv62u/2/

Comment: Also, for comparison you use `==` or `===` and not `=`.

Comment: trim the text before comaring

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/an9erv7a/2/

Comment: version with trimmed code http://jsfiddle.net/p0rcv62u/4/ as @ArunPJohny suggested

Answer (score 3):

That is because in if you are using `=` not `==`. & you should also check for `newLine` character. I am assuming `\n` here.

This line

```
if(this.nextSibling.nodeValue = 'br1')
```

should be

```
if(this.nextSibling.nodeValue == 'br1\n')
```

As @antyrat told just use `remove` for that

```
 $( this.nextSibling ).remove();
 $( this ).remove();
```

**FOR CONTAINS**

```
if(this.nextSibling.nodeValue.indexOf('br')>-1){}
```

Comment: Not only the reason. Also there is new line so should be 'br\n' http://jsfiddle.net/p0rcv62u/2/

Comment: what I want to do is delete that line if nodevalue found, like delete <br>br1 if br1 can be found.

Comment: @antyrat updated my answer for that also.

Comment: @user3836151 http://jsfiddle.net/p0rcv62u/3/ this code will delete br1 if found

Comment: why not using $(this) but only this?

Comment: how about not exact match? like delete if contain string 'br'? sorry I'm a newbie.